# SWRevealViewController not toggle

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement SWRevealViewController in a project without using storyboard. I think it's possible to do but i unfortunately failed. The button in the navigation bar does not perform the "revealToggle" action that is defined on him. So NavigationTableViewController is never shown. I don't understand why... I searched several hours a solution to this problem. Anyone help would be much appreciated.

```
#import "ContentViewController.h"
#import "NavigationTableViewController.h"

@interface ContentViewController()<SWRevealViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ContentViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
//[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];

UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window = window;

ContentViewController *frontViewController = self;
NavigationTableViewController *rearViewController = [[NavigationTableViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];
SWRevealViewController *revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:rearViewController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];
revealController.delegate = self;

[revealController panGestureRecognizer];
[revealController tapGestureRecognizer];


self.viewController = revealController;
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

UIBarButtonItem *revealButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal-icon.png"]
                                                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:revealController action:@selector(revealToggle:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = revealButtonItem;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to solve my problem. According to [John Lluch examples](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/), i modified my code.
Here is the solution without using storyboards :

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SplashScreenController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SplashScreenController *viewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SWRevealViewController *revealController;

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ContentViewController.h"
#import "NavigationTableViewController.h"


@interface AppDelegate()<SWRevealViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    SplashScreenController *frontViewController = [[SplashScreenController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashScreenController" bundle:nil];
    NavigationTableViewController *rearViewController = [[NavigationTableViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];
    SWRevealViewController *revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:rearViewController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];

    revealController.delegate = self;

    self.window.rootViewController = revealController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;

}
```

**ContentViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ContentViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

**ContentViewController.m**

```
#import "ContentViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "NavigationTableViewController.h"
#import <sqlite3.h>

@interface ContentViewController()<SWRevealViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ContentViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    SWRevealViewController *revealController = [self revealViewController];
    [revealController panGestureRecognizer];
    [revealController tapGestureRecognizer];

    UIBarButtonItem *revealButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal-icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:revealController action:@selector(revealToggle:)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = revealButtonItem;

}
```